# HTML page lose formatting on external server

Tags: html, css, highcharts

I have made an HTML page that include some CSS aswell as 2 simple highcharts (highcharts.com)

I have tested this locally on my own computer, and very happy with the result, i moved this to an server on our internal netwrok, for this to be available to everyone.

When the page is loaded from the server, everything appears "wrong", as you can see in the following 2 pictures.

(Im not allowed to post pictures it seems)

http://i46.tinypic.com/jaua7o.png

This is the correct layout.

http://i46.tinypic.com/1zo9dzo.png

This is the incorrect layout. 
As you may be able to see on the incorrect layout, for some reason the letters in the Menu are smaller, and the "gigabyte" to the left of the graphs are suffering from some weird weird stuff. In addition to this, when the graphs are loaded on my local machine, they have some sleek animations, which doesnt show up when loaded from the external server.

Although the letters are smaller than on my local computer, its clear that some of the formatting works as intended, as the menu "sort of" works, and this is made with CSS.

Any hints as to what could cause this? Im kinda confused, as i figured it would be the same whether i load the HTML from my local machine, or from the server.

Thanks a ton in advance.

The code of the particular page (apologise that i havent commentated it):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
         for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == variable) { return pair[1]; }
         }
         return (false);
    }
    var kunde = getQueryVariable("area");

    function onDownload() {
        document.location = 'database' + kunde + '.csv';
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var graph = {
            colors: [
                        '#696567',
                        '#525051'
            ],
            exporting: { enabled: false },
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Imaginært Diskforbrug'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,                      
                title: {
                    text: 'Gigabyte'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -100,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

        $.get("mfdisk" + kunde + ".txt", function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) graph.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    })
                    ;
                }

                else {
                    var series = {
                        data: []

                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });

                    graph.series.push(series);
                }

            });

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(graph);
        });     
    });
            </script>   
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                        var tapegraph = {
                            colors: [
                                     '#525051'
                            ],
                            exporting: { enabled: false },
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'tapecontainer',
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Imaginært Tapeforbrug'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: []
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Gigabyte'
                            },
                            stackLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                style: {
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            align: 'right',
                            x: -100,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 20,
                            floating: true,
                            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                            borderColor: '#CCC',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            shadow: false
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                stacking: 'normal',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: []
                    };

                        $.get("mftape" + kunde + ".txt", function (data) {
                        var lines = data.split('\n');
                        $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
                            var items = line.split(',');

                            if (lineNo == 0) {
                                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    if (itemNo > 0) tapegraph.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                                })
                                ;
                            }

                            else {
                                var series = {
                                    data: []

                                };
                                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                                        series.name = item;
                                    } else {
                                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                    }
                                });

                                tapegraph.series.push(series);
                            }

                        });

                        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(tapegraph);
                    });
                });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
            <ul class="tabmenu">
            <li><a href="csv.html">Forside</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="mfstart.html">Mainframe</a></li>
            <li><a href="">AIX</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Superdome</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
            </ul>
    <div class="menu">
    <a href="mf.html?area=AC">KMA</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=fAC">FrysAC</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=OC">KMO</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=fOC">FrysOC</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=BC">KMB</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=SAP">SAP</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Eboks">Eboks</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=fBC">FrysBC</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=uAZ">Udv - AZ</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=uOZ">Udv - OZ</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=uBZ">Udv - BZ</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=TCS">TCS</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=COOP">COOP</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=U1">KMD Udv1</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=U2">KMD Udv2</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Nem">Nemkonto</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Systest">Systest</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=AKI">ÅKI</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Ribe">Ribe</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Eindkomst">E-indkomst</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=Fyn">Fyns Amt</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=KK">KK</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=KC">KC</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=FDC">FDC</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=ATP">ATP</a>
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 720px; height: 360px; margin: 0 auto"></div>  
    <div id="tapecontainer" style="width: 720px; height: 360px; margin: 0 auto"></div>  
    <div class="downloadlink">
    <a href="javascript:onDownload();">Klik her for at downloade database over kundens forbrug</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

I know that it may appear abundant that i made almost the same code for the 2 graphs, but these will be much different as soon as i get further in the project.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I have added the code, im sorry.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Could be a simple browser caching issue.

Comment: Im using internet explorer 8. But im afraid its not related to caching, as the same problem is in place when a coworker opens the page for the first time.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors reported in the Console?

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, and some time on other projects, i came back to this with fresh eyes. Turned out the problem was caused by the fact that IE9 automatically opens web pages on our local intranet in compatibility mode, i disabled this and it worked like a charm!